# Making an object get a self ellipse

Tags: python, pygame

Is it possible to get an image to self ellipse like you can with the rect. If not is there a way to get a round object to bounce off another round object when they actually touch the object and not just the self rect square. This is what i have got.

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Ball 2.png')
        self.rect= self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = (Width / 2, Height / 2)
        self.speedx = random.randint(ballspeedx, ballspeedx)
        self.speedy = random.randint(ballspeedy, ballspeedy)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.left += self.speedx
        self.rect.top += self.speedy
        if self.rect.right > Width or self.rect.left < 0:
            self.speedx = -self.speedx
        if self.rect.bottom > Height or self.rect.top < 20:
            self.speedy = -self.speedy
class You(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Ball.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = (10, Height -10)
    def update(self):
        if self.rect.right > Width:
            self.rect.right = Width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > Height:
            self.rect.bottom = Height
        if self.rect.top < 20:
            self.rect.top = 20   

ball = Ball()
you = You()
Start = pygame.sprite.Group()
Start.add(ball)
Start2 = pygame.sprite.Group()
Start2.add(you)

if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(you, Start, False):
    running = False
```

Comment: You call it an ellipse but what you describe is a *circle*. It's right there in [the documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) under `collide_rect`.

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear, but if you want to implement physics for circle objects, you could take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-physics-simulation/collisions) by Peter Collingridge. Also, [Pymunk](http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/) is pretty cool, but it can take a while to familiarize yourself with this library.

Answer (score 0):

`Sprite` has

- [pygame.sprite.collide_circle()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle) - to use circles to check collision between two sprites
- [pygame.sprite.collide_mask()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask) - to use bitmaps to check collsion using any shape.

Comment: BTW: see example with [circle collision](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/collisions) and [mask collision](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/mask-collision)